# Last row of some column in dataframe not included

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have tried to find an average of a value for an index 0 before it exchange to another index.
An example of the dataframe:

| column_a | value_b | sum_c | count_d_ | avg_e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 10 | 1 |  |
| 0 | 20 | 30 | 2 |  |
| 0 | 30 | 60 | 3 | 20 |
| 1 | 10 | 10 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 20 | 30 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 30 | 60 | 3 | 20 |
| 0 | 10 | 10 | 1 |  |
| 0 | 20 | 30 | 2 | 15 |
| 1 | 10 | 10 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 20 | 30 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 30 | 60 | 3 | 20 |
| 0 | 10 | 10 | 1 |  |
| 0 | 20 |  |  |  |

however, only the last row for sum and count is unavailable, so the avg cannot be calculated for it

```
part of the code...
#sum and avg for each section

for i, row in df.iloc[0:-1].iterrows():
  if df['column_a'][i] == 0:
    sum = sum + df['value_b'][i]
    df['sum_c'][i] = sum
    count = count + 1
    df['count_d'][i] = count
  else:
    sum = 0 
    count = 0
    df['sum_c'][i] = sum
    df['count_d'][i] = count

totcount = 0
for m, row in df.iloc[0:-1].iterrows():
  if df.loc[m, 'column_a'] == 0 :
    if (df.loc[m+1, 'sum_c'] == 0) :
      totcount = df.loc[m, 'count_d']
      avg_e = (df.loc[m, 'sum_c']) / totcount
      df.loc[m, 'avg_e'] = avg_e
```

have tried only using df.iloc[0:].iterrows but it produce an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite you full code with [`groupby.cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax.html), [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), [`groupby.transform('mean')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and masking with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html).

```
# compute a mask with True for the last value per successive group
m = df['column_a'].ne(df['column_a'].shift(-1))[::-1]
# make a grouper
group = m.cumsum()

# for each group
g = df.groupby(group)['value_b']
# compute the cumsum
df['sum_c'] = g.cumsum()
# compute the cumcount
df['count_d_'] = g.cumcount().add(1)
# compute the mean and assign to the last row per group
df['avg_e'] = g.transform('mean').where(m)
```

Output:

```
    column_a  value_b  sum_c  count_d_  avg_e
0          0       10     10         1    NaN
1          0       20     30         2    NaN
2          0       30     60         3   20.0
3          1       10     10         1    NaN
4          1       20     30         2    NaN
5          1       30     60         3   20.0
6          0       10     10         1    NaN
7          0       20     30         2   15.0
8          1       10     10         1    NaN
9          1       20     30         2    NaN
10         1       30     60         3   20.0
11         0       10     10         1    NaN
12         0       20     30         2   15.0
```

Comment: thank you very much! but if i only want to get the sum and prod for index 0 do I have to use if else function? or just find the sum and prod for index 0 only? @mozway

Comment: what do you mean by "*prod*"? the `cumprod`? If you want to assign only on the first row per group use `first` in place of `last` in my code

Comment: I'm sorry, there is a mistake with my word. What i mean is that i want to calculate only the sum and *avg for index 0 from column_a. everything mentioned above is already correct but i wonder if i can only do it for the index 0, so the calculation will skip the index 1.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can mask with `.where(df['column_a'].eq(1))`

Comment: yes! that's what i meant. thank you very much kind person. really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is the expected behavior of `df.iloc[0:-1]` to return all the rows excepting the last one. When using slicing, remember that **the last index you provide is not included in the return range**. Since `-1` is the index of the last row, `[0:-1]` excludes the last row.

The solution given by @mozway is anyway more elegant, but if for any reason you still want to use `iterrows()`, you can use `df.iloc[0:]`.

The error ou got when you did may be due to your `df.loc[m+1, 'sum_c']`. At the last row, m+1 will be out of bounds and produce an `IndexError`.